# System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'DemoProject.TestResources.StaticClassExample' threw an exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have a static method on a public class named StaticClassExample.

```
public static string GetValue(string res, string key)
   {
       string value = string.Empty;

       value = getValueByLang(res, key, 1);

       // get resource value for default locale
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            value = getValueByLang(res, key, 1);
        }
       return value;
   }
```

in another class i am calling this method as

```
return StaticClassExample.GetValue(_resource, "Success");
```

but every time it gives an exception like:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'DemoProject.TestResources.StaticClassExample' threw an exception.'
>   Inner Exception Must specify valid information for parsing in the
>   string.
>
> Message The type initializer for
>   'DemoProject.TestResources.StaticClassExample' threw an exception.

Comment: Is `GetValue` the only code in `StaticClassExample`? If not then you should post the whole code

Comment: there was some data missing from config file just because of that i was getting that exception so just by adding that value i got fix to the issue.